# $3$ paylines that can sum up simultaneously, slot machine. RTP(return to player)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How to calculate RTP (Slot Machine Return) if,

- The number of symbols is $3$, i.e. black, white, red
- Each symbol appears equally, there may be e.g. $9$ red ones
- symbols are independent, on each of the $9$ fields it is possible to draw $1$/$3$ of a given symbol
- Winning means drawing $3$ symbols of the same level
- There are $3$ paylines simultaneously, that is Top, Middle and Bottom.
- **Lines won can add up**
- Of course, there can also be $1$ or $2$ win lines at once
- The winnings table is not important, it is important that the RTP is around $95 \%$

Comment: Is there any limit on the number of times a symbol can appear?  Can you get $9$ reds for example?  If so, then the number of possibilities is $3^9$ not $9^3$.  Are we to assume that every position has a $\frac13$ chance of being any of the symbols, regardless of the values at the other positions?  That is, are the values independent?

Comment: yes you can get 9 red, my bad

Comment: neither position is in any way dependent on the other, so the values are independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each line, there are $3^3=27$ possibilities and $3$ of them are winners, so the probability of winning is $\frac3{27}=\frac19$, and the probability of losing is $\frac89$.

The probability of winning on all $3$ lines is $\left(\frac19\right)^3=\frac1{729}$.

The probability of winning on exactly $2$ lines is $3\left(\frac19\right)^2\frac89=\frac8{243}$, because there are $3$ ways to choose the losing line.

The probability of wining on exactly one line is $3\left(\frac89\right)^2\frac19=\frac{64}{243}$, because there are $3$ ways to choose the winning line.

The probability of losing on all lines is $\left(\frac89\right)^3=\frac{512}{729}$

As a sanity check,
$$\frac1{729}+\frac8{243}+\frac{64}{243}+\frac{512}{729}=\\
\frac1{729}+\frac{24}{729}+\frac{192}{729}+\frac{512}{729}=\\
\frac{729}{729}=1$$

Comment: So winning one symbol that has a value of, say, $3$ would be $79\%$ return?

According to this equation,
$\frac{64}{243} *3=0,79$

So for all $3$ cases, for example, stating that black has a multiplier of $3$, white $2$ and red $1$, the final return for the player will be $1,58$ so $158\%$?

So if we subtract the cost of the bet is $-1$ the total return to the player would be $58\%$?

[simple exel calculations][1]


  [1]: https://prnt.sc/yl4qto

Comment: I don't understand the payoffs for two winning lines on your spreadsheet.  There are $9$ equally likely ways of winning on two lines, BB, BW, BR, WB, WW, WR, RB, RW, and RR.  Where are the payoffs for these possibilities listed?  You only list $3$ possibilities, and they each have only one symbol.  

I've deleted my comments from yesterday, because we were talking at cross-purposes.  I suggest you delete all of yours, other than the first, to make this post less confusing.

Comment: Ah yes, you could have misunderstood a single symbol win. on the chart I wrote one symbol as a whole line, e.g. $3$ black symbols in one line. The rest of the possibilities of all 9 are not listed, because only two of the same pairs at once result in a larger multiplier as one. And if, for example, during the drawing there will be two black lines, it will be 30 and, for example, one line of reds will be $30 + 1$;

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.  Please just list the $9$ outcomes and what they're worth.